# solving a stationary problem with matlab: descritization

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

The given equation is 
$$
\Delta(-\phi+\phi^3-\Delta\phi)=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}.
$$

I think it is equivalent to $\Delta\phi = \phi^3-\phi$

so I arrived to:

$$
\frac{\phi_{i+1,j}+\phi_{i-1,j}+\phi_{i,j-1}+\phi_{i,j+1}-4\phi_{i,j}}{\delta^2}=\phi_{i,j}^3-\phi_{i,j}
$$

I should have $\phi_{i,j}= ...$ (function not depending on $\phi_{i,j}$) so that I could apply the methods of Jacobi, Gauss-Seidel and SOR that are the theme of the worksheet this question is in.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: You have $\nabla^2(...\nabla^2{\phi})$, in your code, I believe. Is that intended? That could be your error.

Comment: @user57404 my problem is that i can not find an expression not depending on phi(i,j). Maybe i have not been very clear in the way i exposed it

Comment: I am not very efficient with Matlab, nor with numerical analysis. You should wait for someone more experienced to come along with respect to if it is clear or not. I just wasn't sure that you intended what I mentioned in my first comment.  Trying to help :p!

Answer (score 0):

You can not just drop the time derivative and laplacian. That would be a completely different equation which share some solutions with yours.

If you're absolutely sure you need to solve $\Delta \phi = \phi^3 - \phi$ using some interational method for SLAE you need to linearize your problem first.

Start with some initial approximation for the solution $\phi_0$. Assuming it is close to $\phi$ let's introduce new unknown function $\psi = \phi - \phi_0$.
$$
\Delta \psi = \Delta (\phi - \phi_0) = \phi^3 - \phi - \Delta \phi_0 = 
(\phi_0 + \psi)^3 - (\phi_0 + \psi) - \Delta \phi_0 \approx
\phi_0^3 + 3\phi_0 \psi - \phi_0 - \psi - \Delta \phi_0
$$
So we've arrived to 
$$
\Delta \psi + (1 - 3\phi_0)\psi = \phi_0^3 + \phi_0 - \Delta \phi_0
$$
Boundary conditions should be adjusted accordingly (That's what I do not understand. The original problem should have a *pair* of conditions in each point of the boundary while the new one should have only a *single* one. That's an argument against dropping the outer laplacian). Discretizing that problem will result in SLAE for $\psi$ which has meaning of a correcting term for $\phi_0$, so the new approximation for the solution $\phi_1$ would be $\phi_1 = \phi_0 + \psi$. Repeat until convergence. If this method diverges you need to choose a better (closer to the solution) $\phi_0$.